# How to organize my JPanel inside a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grouplayout

I'm having trouble organizing `JPanel` inside a `JFrame`.

I have 3 `JPanel`s and need to organize them as follows:

**panel1  panel2**

**panel__3333333**

However, can only horizontally align `panel1` and `panel2` as follows:

```
 groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addComponent(PANEL1)
        .addComponent(PANEL2));
    groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup()
        .addComponent(PANEL1)
        .addComponent(PANEL2));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to house your JPanels inside of other JPanels.

Here is an example of what you might do:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//this is the main JPanel that will house all of your child JPanels
JPanel mainPanel= (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
//this JPanel will house "panel1" and "panel2" on top and will go inside the main panel
JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
topPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

//add panel1 and panel2 to topPanel here

mainPanel.add(topPanel);

//add panel3 to mainPanel here

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

There are many different approaches to this, but I find this the easiest. Hope this helps!

Comment: This solution worked and the breads are aligned. One more doubt, I can resize the size of each panel?

Comment: Exactly why do you want to resize the JPanels @bbariotti? I don't know of a way to resize JPanels manually, and if there was a way, it will mess up the orientation of the JPanels when the user resizes the window. I would play around with the different layouts and include more JPanels if you want to change the placement and size of your GUI components.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use GridBagLayout instead of a grouplayout.
It matches with your needs

[See the oracle doc on gridbag layout here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)